# The forgetful functor $U:T-Alg\rightarrow C$ preserves limits

Tags: limits, category-theory, algebras, forgetful-functors

Suppose $F$ is an endofunctor of a **complete** category $C$.

> Let $F-Alg$ be the category that has objects the pairs $(X, \ a:FX\rightarrow X)$ where $X$ is an object in $C$, and that has morphisms $f:(X,a)\rightarrow (Y,b)$ where $f$ is a morphisms in $C$ with the property $fa=b\circ Ff$.

Let $M:I\rightarrow F-Alg$ be a diagram with limit $((\lim M,m),\mu_i)$. Show that the forgetful functor $U:F-Alg\rightarrow C$ preserves this limit.

**My attempt.**

I need to show that the limit of $UM$ in $C$ is $(\lim M,\mu_i)$. So suppose $X$ is an object together with maps $\nu_i:X\rightarrow object(Mi)$ satisfying $M\alpha\circ \nu_i=\nu_j$ for each $\alpha:i\rightarrow j$ in $I$. My job is now to find a map  $s:X\rightarrow \lim M$ in $C$ with the property $\mu_i\circ s= \nu_i$.

Of course, by the universal property of limits in $F-Alg$, whenever we have an object $(X,a)$ together with morphisms $\nu_i:(X,a)\rightarrow Mi$ satisfying $M\alpha\circ \nu_i=\nu_j$, there is a unique $k:(X,a)\rightarrow (\lim M,m)$ with the property $\mu_i\circ k= \nu_i$. I would like to choose $s=k$. The issue I am having is that we don’t know if the object $X$ in $C$ has a corresponding object $(X,a)$ in $F-Alg$, because it is not guaranteed that a map $a:FX\rightarrow X$ exists in $C$. I tried to raise the map $k$ to $Fk$ and use it is a morphism in $F-Alg$, but with no success...

How do I ensure $X$ comes with a morphism $a:FX\rightarrow X$?

I added a sketch for clarity

￼

[image]I would prefer a hint over an answer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You are right, T should be F

Comment: I'm not sure about this: but I tried drawing the free category with a product $(P, c)$ of two $F$-algebras $(X, a)$ and $(Y, b)$ along with a test object $U$ and morphisms $U \to X$ $U \to Y$.  (And then that category also has objects $F^n(U), F^n(X), F^n(Y), F^n(P)$ and appications of $F^n$ of the morphisms.)  But I didn't see anything that forced there to be any map $U \to P$ - just maps $F^n(U) \to F^n(P)$ for $n \ge 1$.  So, if I didn't miss something, then I think the poset category generated by this graph will form a counterexample.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I also tried it with products instead of general limits, but ran into the same problem. That U preserves limits is stated on page 60 after exercise 114 in these notes https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/catsmoeder.pdf. I attempted the exercise but I do not see how this implies U preserves limits.

Comment: OK, in those notes, $T$ is assumed to be a monad, not just an endofunctor.  And $T{-}Alg$ has the additional restriction of a compatibility condition with the monad parts of $T$.  Furthermore, the following comment about preserving limits also has the condition that $C$ must have all limits of a given type in the first place.

Comment: In the case of algebras over a monad, one proof that the underlying object functor $T{-}Alg \to C$ preserves limits is simply that it has a left adjoint $C \to T{-}Alg$ which sends an object $X$ of $C$ to $(TX, \mu_X)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I have read this argument too, so for algebras over a monad I can see why U preserves limits. The issue is that my course notes have no mention of monads; they speak only of F-algebras, so I presume it should work there too. In my notes it is also assumed that C is complete, but I don’t see why completeness of C helps me... Can you see how C being complete changes things?

Comment: I don't see immediately how $C$ being complete would help -- but it *would* render my proposed counterexample invalid since there, the entire point was the nonexistence of a certain product.  That would be an important assumption to add to the text of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For simplicity, I'll consider the case of a product of two objects.  Working backwards from the conclusion, if you have two $T$-algebras $(X, f)$ and $(Y, g)$, then the product of these two $T$-algebras will end up being isomorphic to $(X \times Y, h)$ for some $h$.  So, a good place to start would probably be to look for an explicit way to construct a morphism $h : T(X\times Y) \to X\times Y$.  Then, if you can show that this $T$-algebra is a product of $(X, f)$ and $(Y, g)$, you will be done for this type of limit by the uniqueness of limits.  (And then, hopefully, your argument will be straightforward to generalize to more general limits.)

Comment: Incidentally, this is also related to the notion of a functor which "creates limits" as discussed in the notes on monads that you linked in the comments.  Essentially, this proof could be broken down into showing that the underlying object functor creates limits; and then, use the fact (simple to prove) that if a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ creates limits and $\mathcal{D}$ is complete, then $F$ also preserves limits.